# Nginx redirecting too many times

Tags: nginx

I am running into an issue where nginx is somehow redirecting over and over but I don't understand why:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name splunk.trever.me;
  return 301 https://splunk.trever.me$request_uri;
}

# Port 443 https config
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name splunk.trever.me;

  location / {
    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    proxy_pass http://10.0.1.1:8000;
  }

 access_log /var/log/nginx/splunk.trever.me/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/splunk.trever.me/error.log;

}
```

Am I missing something here? I looked at all the documentation and it doesnt seem to be wrong. Does this mean something upstream is sending the browser back to http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
server {

  server_name splunk.trever.me;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    proxy_pass http://10.0.1.1:8000;
  }

 access_log /var/log/nginx/splunk.trever.me/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/splunk.trever.me/error.log;

}
```

Comment: I don't need to declare the listen ports?

Comment: wait, are you using port 8000? Why are you listening on ports 80 and 443?

Comment: Port 8000 is the port Splunk listens on, I have multiple services that run in dockers on this host

Comment: nginx redirects many times because it doesn't know where to go. In this case, you need to add a server listening on port 8000.

Comment: Yes, Splunk is already listening on port 8000, I can access it via http://10.0.1.1:8000 no problems.

Comment: This isn't working all the time, some domains still pull http instead.

Comment: Hi @trver Did you find a solution for the issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the requests using the IF directive in nginx config.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        server_name splunk.trever.me;

        if ($scheme = http) {
          rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://splunk.trever.me/$1 permanent;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_buffers 16 4k;
            proxy_buffer_size 2k;
            proxy_pass http://10.0.1.1:8000;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/splunk.trever.me/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/splunk.trever.me/error.log;
}
```